# Redirect from one domain to another via web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I want to redirect all my pages from one domain to another.

In order to do that I have written the following code in my web.config:

```
<rule name="Domain redirect" >
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="community.mydummysite.com" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydummysite.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

My goal is to redirect all pages from "community.mydummysite.com" to "www.mydummysite.com", however the above code is producing 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the pattern with regex

```
<rule name="Domain redirect" >
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.+$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydummysite.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```